# Change URL of Site Pages Library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have Sharepoint 2010 instance on URL: **http://dale/**
The default location of Site Pages Library is **http://dale/Pages/**
I would like to change this to  **http://dale/Sider/**

Is this possible? If yes, then how? Maybe some kind of redirection is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
Start here:  http://prodactor.blogspot.com/2007/11/sharepoint-moss-url-rewriting.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not as easy as rewriting the url. SharePoint itself will still produce links to the /Pages library through its navigation controles etc. You'd have to fix that too.

Also, when you rewrite the url, you can get problems with editing pages because some of the Ajax calls use the browser url to construct references to the webservices needed.

I would try to get out of doing it ;)

Comment: it's a public facing site, with custom navigation web part, so I hope this solution works out fine, but thanks for warning